# Letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ in proofs

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I've seen proofs regarding supremum and infimum of bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}$ involving an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ and 'hard' inequalities (not necessarily strict, but hard to manipulate algebraically and wrt ordering). Most of what I saw involves the argument "letting $\varepsilon \to 0$" and I'm kind of baffled. Why is this logically valid?

For context, consider this proof showing that $\sup(\frac{1}{A}) = \frac{1}{\inf A}, \inf A > 0$ (Please check if the steps are correct).

*Proof*. $\sup(\frac{1}{A}) \leq \frac{1}{\inf A}$ is easy to show. Now for $\sup(\frac{1}{A}) \geq \frac{1}{\inf A}$,

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $\exists x_{\varepsilon} \in A$ such that $\inf A + \varepsilon > x_{\varepsilon}$. Then $\frac{1}{\inf A + \varepsilon} < \frac{1}{x_{\varepsilon}} \leq \sup(\frac{1}{A})$. Letting $\varepsilon \to 0$, $\frac{1}{\inf A} \leq \sup(\frac{1}{A})$.

Answer (score 1):

You have proven the following:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \frac{1}{\inf A + \epsilon} \le \sup\left(\frac{1}{A}\right)$$

Now, appeal to the following: if $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x$ in a neighborhood of $a$, then
$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) \le \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$$
(provided the limits exist).

Taking $f(\epsilon) = 1/(\inf A + \epsilon)$ and $g(\epsilon) = \sup(1/A)$ (constant function), you get the desired result.

Comment: Someone mind explaining the downvote?

Comment: See the comment I made on another answer.

Answer (score 0):

That works because if a function $f$ is such that $f(x)\leqslant M$ for some constant $M$ and if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\leqslant M$. This is so because, if $l=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and if $l>M$, then there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta\implies\left|f(x)-l\right|<l-M$. But then, if $|x-a|<\delta$,$$l-f(x)=-\bigl(f(x)-l\bigr)\leqslant|f(x)-l|<l-M,$$
and therefore $f(x)>M$. But we are supposing that we always have $f(x)\leqslant M$.

So, in that situation that you have described, since$$(\forall\varepsilon>0):\frac1{\inf(A)+\varepsilon}\leqslant\sup\left(\frac1A\right),$$then$$\frac1{\inf(A)}=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac1{\inf(A)+\varepsilon}\leqslant\sup\left(\frac1A\right).$$

Comment: If you try to show your assertion on limit using the definition, you will need that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \le M +\epsilon$ implies that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \le M$. You still need to argue why one can take $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @ArcticChar I've added a proof of the fact that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\leqslant M$, but I think that you are being over-rigorous here.

Comment: @ArcticChar Are you seriously asking why $L \le M + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ implies $L \le M?$ Suppose that we would have $L > M$ and have a look at $\epsilon:= (L-M)/2$.

Comment: Note that part of the question is asking why $1/\sup (1/A) \le \inf A+\epsilon$ implies $1/\sup (1/A) \le \inf A$. Why not just spell out the contradiction argument directly, instead of risking a circular reasoning? @quantumspace

Comment: @ArcticChar Is there any circular reasoning in my answer?

Comment: The comment is not directed tp you, @jose